# Cant Return Multiple Values In Python

Tags: python, return-value

I'm trying to return a tuple from a function but it only returns the first element , When I looked online all the resources said Its done the way I did it , any thoughts ? my code :

```
def depthFirst(initialState):
    exploredCount = 1
    visitedCount = 0
    frontier=[]
    frontier.append(initialState)
    explored=[]
    while len(frontier) > 0:
        state=frontier.pop()
        explored.append(state)
        visitedCount = visitedCount + 1
        if state in goalStates:
            return state
        nextStates=getNextStates(state)
        for i in range(len(nextStates)):
            if not nextStates[i] in frontier and not nextStates[i] in explored:
                frontier.append(nextStates[i])
                exploredCount = exploredCount + 1

    return [initialState , exploredCount , visitedCount]
```

Im callingthe function like this :

```
    ans = depthFirst(state)
    arr = ans[0]
    explored = arr[1]
    visited = arr[2]
```

Comment: So what's the initial value of `state`? What does `getNextStates` do?

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is due to the part of the function below:

```
if state in goalStates:
        return state
```

The above is ran before the last line of the function is reached. Therefore the function works until the first `return` (seen above) and only returns `state` and not the list `[initialState , exploredCount , visitedCount]`

Comment: That was the issue , stupid hahaha , thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Its returning fine, your first element doesn't have an index of 1

```
ans = depthFirst(state)

# should work fine
print(ans[0])
print(ans[1])
print(ans[2])

arr = ans[0]
explored = arr[1] # arr doesn't have index 1
visited = arr[2]
```

EDIT: this is assuming you reach the final return statement and not returning early like the other answer suggest.